# How to find null byte in a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, null, byte

I'm having an issue parsing data after reading a file. What I'm doing is reading a binary file in and need to create a list of attributes from the read file all of the data in the file is terminated with a null byte. What I'm trying to do is find every instance of a null byte terminated attribute.

Essentially taking a string like

```
Health\x00experience\x00charactername\x00
```

and storing it in a list.

The real issue is I need to keep the null bytes in tact, I just need to be able to find each instance of a null byte and store the data that precedes it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While it boils down to using `split('\x00')` a convenience wrapper might be nice.

```
def readlines(f, bufsize):
    buf = ""
    data = True
    while data:
        data = f.read(bufsize)
        buf += data
        lines = buf.split('\x00')
        buf = lines.pop()
        for line in lines:
            yield line + '\x00'
    yield buf + '\x00'
```

then you can do something like

```
with open('myfile', 'rb') as f:
    mylist = [item for item in readlines(f, 524288)]
```

This has the added benefit of not needing to load the entire contents into memory before splitting the text.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the issue I have though is I forgot to say in my initial question I need to keep all of the nullbyte in place, I just need to be able to take the input and find the nullbyte, sorry I didn't clarify that initially

Comment: @user2806298 Edited to keep the nullbytes in place

Answer (score 11):

Python doesn't treat NUL bytes as anything special; they're no different from spaces or commas. So, [`split()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) works fine:

```
>>> my_string = "Health\x00experience\x00charactername\x00"
>>> my_string.split('\x00')
['Health', 'experience', 'charactername', '']
```

Note that `split` is treating `\x00` as a *separator*, not a *terminator*, so we get an extra empty string at the end. If that's a problem, you can just slice it off:

```
>>> my_string.split('\x00')[:-1]
['Health', 'experience', 'charactername']
```

Comment: I forgot to say in my initial question I need to keep all of the nullbyte in place, I just need to be able to take the input and find the nullbyte, sorry I didn't clarify that initially

Comment: @user2806298: As justhalf implies, Python's `str.split` method doesn't  have any way to keep the separators, but it's easy to just add them back on to each one. For example: `[s+'\x00' for s in my_string.split('\x00')[:-1]]`.

Answer (score 4):

To check if string has NULL byte, simply use `in` operator, for example:

```
if b'\x00' in data:
```

To find the position of it, use [`find()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) which would return the lowest index in the string where substring sub is found. Then use optional arguments *start* and *end* for slice notation.

Answer (score 1):

Split on null bytes; `.split()` returns a list:

```
>> print("Health\x00experience\x00charactername\x00".split("\x00"))
['Health', 'experience', 'charactername', '']
```

If you know the data always ends with a null byte, you can slice the list to chop off the last empty string (like `result_list[:-1]`).

Comment: Yeah the extra slash present in error
  
 
I forgot to say in my initial question I need to keep all of the nullbyte in place, I just need to be able to take the input and find the nullbyte, sorry I didn't clarify that initially