# Source code string cannot contain null bytes in python terminal, windows

Tags: python, pip, traceback

I just installed python in my windows 10 pc. I am getting this weird error which I have never seen before:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\program files\python\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\program files\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "c:\program files\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "c:\program files\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "c:\program files\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.parser import ConfigOptionParser
  File "c:\program files\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.configuration import Configuration, ConfigurationError
  File "c:\program files\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\configuration.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils import appdirs
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

Comment: What is the code that causes it?

Comment: My first guess would be that your installation is damaged.  I would uninstall and reinstall first.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233777/python-source-code-string-cannot-contain-null-bytes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970830/how-to-find-null-byte-in-a-string-in-python